# PHP redirection based on DNS

Tags: php

say i have a file named redirections.txt that looks like this:

```
www: http://www.example.com/hub/
icloud: http://www.example.com/icloud/
dev: http://www.example.com/development/latest/projects.php
```

how would i go about processing that text document as `domain-prefix: redirect-url`? (or "if $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] equals domain-prefix.example.com, goto redirect-url")

currently i have:

```
$file = file('redirections.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach($file as $line => $cont){
    preg_match('/(*.?): http:\/\/www.example.com\/(*.?)\//', $cont, $matches);
    print_r($matches); // Debug. Was trying to see if it worked.
}
```

Comment: Your loop looks like it should work. What's the problem with it?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will never equal the domain prefix. `HTTP_HOST` is a fully-qualified name, so it will be something like `www.yourdomain.com`.

Comment: Couldn't you do this in a rewrite rule in the server configuration, instead of PHP?

Comment: @Barmar I'm choosing this over rewrite for some reasons i'll keep private. Also, i'm aware http_host won't equal it. I mean't domain-prefix.example.com. I'll fix that.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like your regular expression should work. You could also use `explode(': ', $cont)` to split the line at the `:`.

Comment: @Barmar Could you make an answer as to how to use explode exactly? that sounds like a better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode()` to split the line:

```
$split = explode(': ', $cont);
if (count($split) == 2) {
    list ($domain_prefix, $redirect_url) = $split;
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "$domain_prefix.example.com") {
        header("Location: $redirect_url");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways to achieve want you want, but if you need to use the code already presented, try this:

```
foreach($file as $line => $cont){
    preg_match('/(?P<domain>\w+): http:\/\/www.example.com(?P<path>\/.*)/', $cont, $matches);
    print_r($matches); // Debug.
```

Comment: I don't need to. But thanks. I'm just not allowed to use rewrite methods because my client believes it's a security risk, even though i explained a million times it's not.